# How to calculate total price of products based on quantity of products in Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary, google-cloud-firestore, shopping-cart

I am making an ecommerce site using React and firebase firestore for polishing my react skills but for some days I have been stuck in quiet a problem. I have a component named IndividualCartProducts which is the result of map function on CartProducts. IndividualCartProducts has some JSX rendered. I have a select tag for selecting quantity of a product in IndividualCartProducts which is changing the price of that particular product but this is hardcoded...I have done something like this to achieve this.

```
 <label htmlFor="CurrencySign">Rs</label>
 <input type="text" className='form-control'
  value={IndividualCart.ProductPrice * quantity} // this is what I mean with hardcoded
  required readOnly disabled/>
```

I just want to calculate total price based on quantity of product but I am unable to have any idea how to do that. I **think** It will be done by manipulating the array, by updating the price of that particular product depending on quantity in that array but so far I am failing to do that.

Hear me out a little more, I have 3 components related to my question 1) appjs 2) CartsProducts 3) IndividualCartProducts.

there is a button add to cart in my IndividualCartProducts which triggers a function and this function is actually recieved as a prop from appjs. In appjs In the function I recieved all the product information and pushed it to the firestore

```
 // add to cart
  addToCart = (ProductID, ProductName, ProductDescription, ProductPrice, ProductImg) => {
    auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      if (user) {
        db.collection('cart ' + user.uid).doc(ProductID).set({
          ProductID, ProductName, ProductDescription, ProductPrice, ProductImg
        }).then(() => console.log('successfully added to cart')).catch(err => console.log(err.message))
      }
      else {
        console.log('sign in first');
      }
    })
  }
```

then in componentDidMount(), I retrived that product data and updating the state of cart

```
// getting cart data and setting state
    const cartProducts = this.state.Cart;
    auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      if (user) {
        db.collection('cart ' + user.uid).onSnapshot(snapshot => {
          let changes = snapshot.docChanges();
          changes.forEach(change => {
            if (change.type === 'added') {
              cartProducts.push({
                CartProductID: change.doc.id,
                ProductName: change.doc.data().ProductName,
                ProductDescription: change.doc.data().ProductDescription,
                ProductPrice: change.doc.data().ProductPrice,
                ProductImg: change.doc.data().ProductImg
              })
            }
            else if (change.type === 'removed') {
              for (var i = 0; i < cartProducts.length; i++) {
                if (cartProducts[i].CartProductID === change.doc.id) {
                  cartProducts.splice(i, 1);
                }
              }
            }
            this.setState({
              Cart: cartProducts,
              noOfProductsInCart: this.state.Cart.length,
            })
            // console.log(this.state.Price);
          })
        })
      }
      else {
        console.log('user is not signed in to retrive cart data');
      }
    })
```

now I passed this state to CartProducts applied map function their and return a component named IndividualCartProducts and in their return JSX. If you need anymore information please let me know, this is my first question here and I am react beginner too. Any hint, idea, logic, any code will be most appreciated

full code can be found here on github https://github.com/HamzaAnwar1998/EcommerceWithReact

Answer (score 0):

Keep a array with product price and quantity and just loop over to calculate total